# How to show user [Commentator] role in commment page of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, printf, comments, echo

i am trying to show wordpress registered users role like - subscriber, author, editor etc.

into comment page of wordpress.

for that i created this code

```
<?php //get the commented user id
$user_id   = get_comment(get_comment_ID())->user_id;

if ($user_id)
{
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id );
    echo implode(', ', $user_info->roles) ;
} ?>
```

it is working fine for me

If commentator's name is KING KHAN and he is subscriber then it shows

KING KHAN [subscriber]

but if the user is being deleted then into the comment page in comment of that user it shows

***KING KHAN[ Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/USERACCOUNT/public_html/wp-includes/class-walker-comment.php on line 277]***

Here instead of this i want to show

***KING KHAN[Member Deleted]***

please edit above code for this

Comment: check if `$user_info` is not empty/set before you use `implode()`. If it is empty `echo` the phrase you want to use.

Comment: could you make correct the code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php //get the commented user id
$user_id   = get_comment(get_comment_ID())->user_id;

if ($user_id)
{
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id );
    if ( isset($user_info->roles) ) {
       echo implode(', ', $user_info->roles) ;
    } else {
       echo 'Member Deleted';
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Hi @RST, Can you tell me where did you add this code? I tried in `comments.php` (In my guessed position) and in `functions.php` also but it doesn't make any difference! I am adding this in `twenty sixteen` theme.

Comment: @Rishabh I only concerned myself with the actual code not with where to use it. You will have to ask the OP

Answer (score 0):

You need to use condition as I did on following code.

```
if ($user_id)
{
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id );
    if(isset($user_info) && is_array($user_info->roles)) {
       echo implode(', ', $user_info->roles) ;
    }else{
       echo "Member Deleted";
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess that is what I suggested already. Keep in mind `is_array()` is really slow on a not set variable.